# Running Docker on native Windows containers fails

Tags: windows-10, container, docker-for-windows

I want to use the current Docker Edge build to run containers natively on my Windows 10 Pro laptop.

But every time I try to pull a container I get an error saying that the vhdx can neither be compressed or encrypted. My hard drive is not compressed and I turned BitLocker off but it didn't help.

Does anyone know what I need to adjust on my system? If you need more information just tell me.

Comment: Yeah I meant natively, but I don't use a VM. I want to use windows native containers

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it to work. Apparently my hard drive wasn't compressed, but the docker folders were for an unknown reason. After changing that it worked.

But I will switch back to the Hyper-V host, because I cannot start any container.